# Is there a way to embed TightVNC Java Viewer without all those buttons?

Tags: java, tightvnc, tightvnc-jviewer

I am playing with the TightVNC viewer for Java and can't find the way to embed the VNC screen (Viewer) into my JFrame window. I do not want a separate window. In fact I do not want any of those (useful, but sometimes not required) buttons.

Simply put, I want to have a JFrame with VNC viewer taking the whole window, and all other stuff from the TightVNC viewer hidden.

Any ideas how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TigerVNC and TightVNC are almost the same (1st depends on the 2nd), but TigerVNC is organized a bit different. Because I don't think it would add up explaining everything for TightVNC in detail I'd suggest using TigerVNC instead, if it is possible license-wise ... maybe your problem doesn't exist there. The steps are the same (trace through the code or something... to find the places where the viewport is assembled) for all Java GUI applications, just the classes have other names.

Comment: To be honest, I did not know that TightVNC had Java client... I will definitely give it a try!